# How can change position of canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, canvas

How can change runtime position of a canvas in which dynamically I added controls like (labels, lines)?

I can zoom canvas with all controls but I can't move in another position with MouseMove, MouseUp, MouseDown.

```
<Canvas Name="canvas" Width="1000" Height="400"
            Margin="100 0 0 50"
            Background="White"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            MouseWheel="Canvas_MouseWheel"
            MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"
            MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp"
            MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown">
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" />
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    </Canvas>
```

I find this code in internet but for my case is not working

```
bool activated;
    Point point;

    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        activated = true;
        point = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
        Mouse.Capture(canvas);
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (activated)
        {
            double top = Canvas.GetTop(canGraph) + Mouse.GetPosition(canvas).Y - point.Y;
            Canvas.SetTop(canvas, top);
            double left = Canvas.GetLeft(canvas) + Mouse.GetPosition(canvas).X - point.X;
            Canvas.SetLeft(canvas, left);
            point = Mouse.GetPosition(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        activated = false;
        Mouse.Capture(null);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit - The previous solution that I provided was not going to work after the first move of the element without more code so here's a better one**

In order to be working correctly the canvas element have to be aligned to the coordinate system of it's parent, which we achieve as we put the canvas in top left corner, if you don't put it there you have to calculate the difference yourselve.

**Code behind**

```
private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        canvas.CaptureMouse();
    }

    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (canvas.IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            translate.X = e.GetPosition(container).X;
            translate.Y = e.GetPosition(container).Y;
        }
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        canvas.ReleaseMouseCapture();
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Grid Background="Green" x:Name="container">
    <Canvas Name="canvas" Width="100" Height="100"
        Margin="0 0 0 0"
        Background="Purple"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"

        MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown">
        <StackPanel Background="White">

        <TextBlock >asdasda</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock >cccc</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock >aaaaa</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock >bbbb</TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" />
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
</Grid>
```

---

**Original answer**

---

**XAML**

I'd do something like this:

- Add a translate transform and to keep you previous transform put it in a group
- Use translate transform in order to move the canvas with positions from the mouse events
- For starting point of your translations you can use coordinates in the container

**Code behind:**

```
bool activated;
    Point point;

    private void Canvas_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        activated = true;
        point = e.GetPosition(container);
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (activated)
        {
            translate.X = e.GetPosition(container).X - point.X;
            translate.Y = e.GetPosition(container).Y - point.Y;
        }
    }

    private void Canvas_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        activated = false;
    }
```

**XAML**

```
<Canvas Name="canvas" Width="100" Height="100"
        Margin="0 0 0 0"
        Background="Purple"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        MouseMove="Canvas_MouseMove"
        MouseUp="Canvas_MouseUp"
        MouseDown="Canvas_MouseDown">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform x:Name="st" />
                <TranslateTransform x:Name="translate" />
            </TransformGroup>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
</Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks, I can move now canvas, but when I moved is blink all elements in canvas. The variable container in my case is canvas, right?

Comment: After mouse down then again I move the canvas is start to move from first position when is been.

Comment: I had a few minutes and noticed that, check out the edit please. If you have trouble I'll help if I find some time again :)

Comment: Now is working very good. I change the edit your code. In MouseDown add point = e.GetPosition(container); from before you edit your code and in MouseMove change to translate.X = e.GetPosition(container).X - point.X; And now is working perfect. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

After mouse down then again I move the canvas is start to move from first position when is been.

P.s.

I add this for more stable code , but always return back to the first position

```
 private void Canvas_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        activated = false;
    }
```